# Display-only character substitution in VIM

Tags: vim

Is there any way to set VIM that it substitutes characters in the displayed text without changing the underlying file?

To be specific, I would like to substitute SOH characters (displayed as ^A by default) for tab to make the FIX protocol log files more readable.

I'm partially fine with a workaround

```
:highlight SpecialKey guifg=#ffffff
```

what makes the ^A invisible on white background but the substitution for tab would be much better.

*Update:*

I've almost found the solution:

```
:syntax match SOH /^A/ conceal cchar=_
:set conceallevel=2
:hi conceal guibg=NONE
```

Unfortunately I haven't found the way how to escape tab to the *cchar* parameter (instead of the underscore).

Comment: What about `:set list`?

Comment: According to documentation: `The character cannot be a control character such as Tab.` See `:h syn-cchar`

Comment: @mouviciel I can't see how the `:set list` could be helpful. Please provide an example.

Comment: `:set list` will activate list mode. which will show nonprintable charachters. In this mode you can conceal a limited number of chars including: tab, eol, space, trail, ... (`:h listchars`) that unfortunately SOH is not one of them. Infact `:set list` and `:set listchars=eol:<` in relation with each other Do exatly what you are done here with ^A ;)

Answer (score 0):

I do face the problem while opening log files.

I use autocommands to do such substitutions and leave files without saving.

```
 :au BufEnter *.log :%s/^M/\r/g
```

This autocommand will replace all ^M characters with newlines while opening a log file.

So, the text like `ADM-DEVICE : logged in^MADM-DEVICE : in prompt` will be shown correctly as

`ADM-DEVICE : logged in
ADM-DEVICE : in prompt`.

Similarly, other control characters can be replaced. One thing I would do is changing '^[' to ` for better understanding.

Log files should not be edited and saved manually. So, for that I will use another autocommand.

```
  :au BufWrite *.log :q!
```

This autocommand will exit the file if I try to save it. Autocommands will be the best choice to do automatically what you wanted to do.